# Open subsets of Jet Bundles

Tags: differential-topology, jet-bundles

I am currently reading through 'Stable mappings and their singularities' by Golubitsky and Guillemin. There they define
$$
J^k(X, Y)_{x, y}
$$
to be the set of equivalence classes of smooth maps $f: X\to Y$ with $f(x) = y$ under the equivalence $\sim_k$, where $f \sim_k g$ if $f, g$ have $k$-th order contact at $x$. Then they define the Jet Bundle as
$$
J^k(X, Y) := \sqcup_{\{x, y\} \in X\times Y} J^k(X, Y)_{x, y}
$$

Later they go on to define charts on $J^k(X, Y)$: given $(\phi, U), (\psi, V)$ charts on $X, Y$ respectively, they define a chart
$$
J^k(U, V)\to \phi(U) \times \psi(V) \times B_{n, m}^k
$$
where $B_{n, m}^k$ is a space consisting of $m$-tuples of polynomials in $n$ variables up to and including degree $k$, with zero constant term. What bothers me is related to the fact that they do not even define a topology on $J^k(X, Y)$. Implicit in their definition of the above charts is the assumption that $J^k(U, V)$ is even a subset of $J^k(X, Y)$, clearly it isn't strictly a subset with the above definitions, but what would a natural injection look like? I know that jets carry local information, so there should be a natural injection, but I can't see one with these definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell they are defining the topology on $J^k(X,Y)$ by the given charts. $J^k(U,V)$ is a subset of $J^k(X,Y)$, bearing in mind that in the jet setting we are viewing functions purely as the coordinates of the jet space. i.e. you don't have to worry about the difference between $f|_U$ and $f$, they both have the same coordinates (value of $f$ at its $k$ derivatives at the point).

Comment: Right. I guess my question is this then: If we have a smooth map $U \to V$, is this necessarily the restriction of some smooth map $X \to Y$? If not, I don't see how $J^k(U, V)$ could be a subset of $J^k(X, Y)$.

Comment: Oh okay! In which case yes, assuming we're working with smooth maps of smooth manifolds. We can just take a bump function which equals $f$ on $U$.

Comment: Bump functions allows us to extend smooth functions $U \to \mathbb{R}$ to smooth functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$. What construction would allow as to extend more general maps $U \to V$ ?

Comment: I see now. If $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then this can be done by just multiplying by a bump function. But in this case $V$ is diffeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ being the domain of a chart, so it works out!

Comment: Exactly! Sorry I should've been a bit more explicit.