# Local chart for Jet bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

I was reading M,Golubitsky & V.Guillemin's book Stable Mappings and Their Singularities ,in theorem 2.7 (page 40)

Which construct the smooth structure on Jet bundle as follows:

Let $U$ be the domain for a chart $\phi$ on $X$ and $V$ be the domain for a chart $\psi$ on $Y$. Let $U^{\prime}=\phi(U)$ and $V^{\prime}=\psi(V)$. Then $\left(\phi^{-1}\right)^{*} \psi_{*}: J^{k}(U, V) \rightarrow$
$J^{k}\left(U^{\prime}, V^{\prime}\right)$ and $\tau_{u, v} \equiv T_{U^{\prime}, V^{\prime}} \cdot\left(\phi^{-1}\right)^{*} \psi_{*}: J^{k}(U, V) \rightarrow U^{\prime} \times V^{\prime} \times B_{n, m}^{k} .$ Give
$J^{k}(X, Y)$ the manifold structure induced by declaring that $\tau_{u, v}$ is a chart. Which needs to prove transition is smooth then.

I found a post here that has exactly the same question,[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3922222/360262).

**My question is on the $J^{k}(U,V) \subset J^k(X,Y)$,if we take bump function multiply with $f$ which needs not to have compact support,which means it needs not coincide with $f$ on whole $U$?**

Comment: Take a larger open set $\tilde U$ and a bump function supported on $\tilde U$ which is $1$ on $U$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin thank you,I have thought about this type of standard argument, then this means $f $ can be extended to the larger open set $\tilde{U}$. which may not even have a continuous extension?(due to some topological obstraction)

Comment: No, no, you get a global extension!

Comment: Thank you professor,I see the embedded submanifold exist local extension ,but the problem here is if we consider some closed subset ,the local extension will have some room outside it,while for open set $U$ here,the neiborhood that it extended to may be itself!No room outside ${U}$? @Ted Shifrin

Comment: Only if $U=X$? ….

Comment: I'm not sure,maybe it over complicated problem I prefer to use the $\pi^{-1}(U\times V)$ as chart better.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin there is an example to make this local extension fails,taking $U = (0,\infty)\subset X = \Bbb{R}$ and $f = 1/x$ no extension to larger neiborhood

Comment: Of course what I said was  nonsense,. You’re right. But their context is to start with a global function in the first place and get a local chart by restricting it, not vice versa.

Comment: I see thank you for your help.